# Stack elements under each other inside ion-item

Tags: angular, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to stack items vertically under each other inside an ion-item:

```
<ion-item>    
  <ion-item-divider style="width: 100%;" item-content>
    <h4>Questions</h4>
  </ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item item-content style="width: 100%;" class="no-border">
    <label style="width: 100%;" item-content>This is a label</label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-toolbar style="width: 100%;" item-content class="transparent-toolbar" text-center>
    <button ion-button icon-only type="button">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button icon-only type="button" >
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-item>
```

However it is not working and the output looks like this:

[image]

This is a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-z1argg?file=pages/home/home.html) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<ion-list>` for this.

Demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-elements-under-each-other-inside-ion-item?file=pages/home/home.html)**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-divider style="width: 100%;" item-content>
        <h4>Questions</h4>
    </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item item-content style="width: 100%;" class="no-border">
        <label style="width: 100%;" item-content>This is a label</label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-toolbar style="width: 100%;" item-content class="transparent-toolbar" text-center>
        <button ion-button icon-only type="button">
            <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
        </button>

        <button ion-button icon-only type="button">
            <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 6, use : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item-group

> Item groups are containers that organize similar items together. They can contain item dividers to divide the items into multiple sections. They can also be used to group sliding items.

```
<ion-item-group>
    <ion-item>
       <ion-label>...</ion-label>
       <ion-button>...</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
       <ion-label>...</ion-label>
       <ion-button>...</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```